# Native USB tethering of wifi (not mobile data)

Tags: usb-tethering

I would like to know if later versions of Android natively support USB tethering of the phone's wifi connections. If so, after which version?

I know that there are custom ROMs that allow you to use the phone's wifi connections via USB tethering. I'm asking if this functionality comes out of the box for all manufacturer ROMs as well.

Comment: as a footnote: I'm interested in buying a new phone to make use of my carrier's mobile-only wifi hotspots (FreeWifi_secure) on my laptop. Directly connecting to these wifi hotspots from my laptop is practically impossible due to the eap-sim authentication they require.

Answer (score 0):

[This is probably not the complete answer you're looking for, I can't comment though]

I'm running a Nexus 4 with 4.4.2 and it supports tethering of the wifi connection out of the box. I think it was already able to do that when I got it , meaning this should work at least with >= 4.2.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to do this as well. I am not interested in tethering to my cellular data, but to WiFi only. I'm on a Nexus 5x running Lollipop.